# How do I set the 'brush hardness' on itext canvas stroke lines?

Tags: itext7

The base of my exploration into itext7 for Java was the [c03e02_premierleague jumpstart tutorial](https://kb.itextsupport.com/home/it7kb/examples/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-chapter-3). The following line of code is probably the one that needs some function added to make the line have a sharper edge, but although I have looked through the list of available methods, I could not make out the one that would achieve this.

```
canvas.moveTo(llx, lly)
    .lineTo(urx, lly)
    .lineTo(urx, ury - r)
    .curveTo(urx, ury - r * b, urx - r * b, ury, urx - r, ury)
    .lineTo(llx + r, ury)
    .curveTo(llx + r * b, ury, llx, ury - r * b, llx, ury - r)
    .lineTo(llx, lly).stroke();
```

After a few problems like for example the line stroke not closing with `closePathStroke()`, I saw that the canvas stroke lines method used for the header cells is different from the `SolidBorder`s used for the other cells.

The borders created using a `PdfCanvas` gray out to the edges of the line, whereas the standard borders go directly from black to white. Clear, sharp edges is what I want on all of those lines.

Here a screenshot zoomed into the top right corner of my slightly modified version of this example (purposefully left in the not properly rendered state to clarify my point).

[image: screenshot zoomed into the top right corner of my slightly modified version of this example (purposefully left in the not properly rendered state to clarify my point)]

Comment: Your *moveTo* and *lineTo* commands put plain vector graphics instructions into the pdf content stream in question. So they are as sharp as possible. What makes a renderer gray them out at the edge, is that the lines and their thickness don't correspond exactly with the pixels of the screen. What might help, is setting the line thickness to 0 before drawing those lines. A thickness of 0 is defined as the thinnest line that can be drawn on the output medium.

Comment: Tried the line-thickness-to-0 trick, but sadly it didn't work either. vector-graphics-line is still shades of gray even though I set the stroke color to black.

Comment: Which PDF viewer do you use?

Comment: Adobe Acrobat Reader